# Lock wp_users table in wordpress will stop wordpress or not

Tags: php, wordpress

My website gets hacked daily and most of the time hacker changed the username and password. If i will give the read access to the wp_users table than will it give any error while running wordpress or not. Because right now i am having only 1 user to post and need not any other user.

1. Will it solve the problem of password and username changing or not.... ??
2. How to do it ?

Comment: I think a good way to know is to try it since some extensions may have different permission requirements. That said however, if the hacker can change the username/password, he could probably just as well wipe out all your posts or most of your database, so changing username/password may not be your biggest problem.

Comment: Ya thats the problem and we cannot lock whole databse

Comment: Well, then you'll basically have to fix your security vulnerabilities. If the hacker can get to the database, he/she has all the power to do anything to your site.

Comment: I am just replacing all my details now than will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all update your WordPress installation to the latest stable release. Change FTP, SSH, MySql passwords and install and configure https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/ and/or https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/ (or other (https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=security)... these are the ones I've used). And you should be safe from hackers ... unless you have installed some unsafe plugin.

Comment: How we know that its unsafe plugin and i am using itheme security plugin

Comment: Install only plugins that are rated and reviewed on the WordPress site and update them to the latest release.

Comment: i have only 11 plugins and everyone is very famous

Comment: Change your FTP,SSH and MySql passwords. Your accounts might be compromised.

Comment: ok i will do that and take this chance too.... than chk it again. Will got know in just 2 days it worked or not

Comment: Scan your computer for malware also. You might have some kind of malware that steals passwords.